# Using Knockout.js bindings to display errors on a form

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'd like to use [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com) to highlight errors on a form.  Some of these errors might be generated through client-side validation, and some of them might come from the server when the form is saved.  Ideally, I'd like the template to look like this:

```
<label data-bind="css: { error: Errors.ProjectName }">Project Name<input data-bind="value: ProjectName" /></label>
```

If `Errors.ProjectName` was true-ish, then the above `<label>` would have a CSS class of `error`.

However, to do this I think I'd have to make `Errors` something like:

```
this.Errors = {
   ProjectName: ko.observable(false),
   FieldA: ko.observable(false),
   FieldB: ko.observable(false),
   // ... Every single field
};
```

Which is a maintenance nightmare, as this form has many, *many* fields.  So, rather than do that, I'd like the model to somehow contain a list of error fields.  More like:

```
this.Errors = ko.observableArray( [] );
```

When my code becomes aware of an error, I can simply set that array to a list of fields that contain errors:

```
model.Errors( ['ProjectName'] ); // ProjectName is invalid
```

The template would then become:

```
<label data-bind="css: { error: Errors.indexOf('ProjectName') >= 0  }">Project Name<input data-bind="value: ProjectName" /></label>
```

This works, however it seems rather messy to me having to check observable array indexes in the template.  The part of me that's trying to master Knockout demands a cleaner, easier to read method.

Some might argue that Knockout.js is not the right tool to use to display error messages and validate the UI.  This is probably a valid opinion.  However, I like the idea of having a single model to store errors, and as errors are added or removed from that model, error messages and highlighted fields on the UI automatically reflect these changes, and the state of the data can easily be queried at any time.

**Question:** What is the cleanest way of implementing error highlighting where the model contains a list of fields in error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preference has been to use something like an `isValid` or `hasError` sub-observable on an observable to track its state.  So, your view model would look like:

```
this.ProjectName = ko.observable();
this.ProjectName.hasError = ko.observable();  //or can be a computed, if it will handle keeping itself updated
```

Then, you can bind like:

```
<label data-bind="css: { error: ProjectName.hasError  }">Project Name<input data-bind="value: ProjectName" /></label>
```

The other nice thing about the "sub-observables" is that they will drop off when converting your data back into JSON to send to the server.

We have an example in the KO docs of using extenders to add the sub-observables: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html#live_example_2_adding_validation_to_an_observable

Also, you may want to look at [Knockout-Validation](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation), as it uses a similar approach.

Comment: Wonder if there's a way to get the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to automatically add those `hasError` observables to each mapped field.

Comment: You can look at the `create` callback of the mapping plugin: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing_object_construction_using_create

Comment: I'm trying to avoid solutions where I have to manually call out every single field.  There's tons of them, and I don't want to list them all out in code.  However, maybe there's no way around this.

Comment: A really interesting pattern than you can use for your case (where you don't have great control over object creation and/or using the mapping plugin options is a burden) is to use a custom binding to attach the "sub-observable" for validation.  It could look something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/A62UU/. If this doesn't quite fit your scenario let me know and we can tweak it a bit.

Comment: The server-side validation is throwing a wrench into things.  The server gives me a key indicating which field is invalid, but I'm having a hard time resolving that key to a field in the model.  For simple stuff it works, but some fields are nested in objects within objects within objects.  I think the approach of storing validation state as sub-observables is a dead end.  I'll probably end up using a separate `Errors` object on the model with all the error information and field mappings.

Comment: Are the server-side errors themselves nested?  Are the keys a unique identifier (doesn't matter what level nested)?  If so, you build an index object out of the errors, place it at the top-level of your view model and index into it using `$root`.

Comment: Yea, I think that's what I'll be doing..  I had most of it working, but I went home for the night..

Comment: Marking this as the answer since it's an overall good overview of Knockout validation.  I'll post the solution I ended up using in a bit.